# How to set a delayed in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm aware or the `Thread.sleep()` and `postDelayed()` function in java/androidStudio.
But here is the issue, I'm creating a replicate of Simon says game.

I created a `generateSequence()` function that puts number of 1-9 randomly into an array called `sequence`. After that, I need to display these sequence, which basically changes the background of a textView for a second and then back to its original background using the `postDelayed()` function.

Here is my code:

```
private void displaySequence(){
    for(int i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++) {
        if(sequence.get(i) == 1) {
            viewCard11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_view_circle4);
            proceed = false;
            handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                viewCard11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_view_circle3);
                proceed = true;
            }, 1000);
        } 
        else if(sequence.get(i) == 2) {} 
        else if(sequence.get(i) == 3) {} 
        else if(sequence.get(i) == 4) {} 
        else if(sequence.get(i) == 5) {} 
        else if(sequence.get(i) == 6) {} 
        else if(sequence.get(i) == 7) {} 
        else if(sequence.get(i) == 8) {} 
        else if(sequence.get(i) == 9) {}
        while(!proceed) {}
    }
}
```

But the problem with `postDelayed()` is that only whatever is inside the function is delayed. Meaning if this `sequence` had 2 element, it will simultaneously blink the background. The `for` loop doesn't wait for the `postDelayed` to finish whatever it is suppose to do, but instead it increments and proceed to put the next `postDelayed`.

To solve this issue, I tried to use a `proceed` boolean variable as a delay. What I do is that, before we call the `postDelayed`, I set `proceed` as `false`. Since it will not wait for `postDelayed()`, it will go to the next line of code which is the `while` loop.

By setting the `proceed` as false, I use it to create a infinite loop. But this infinite loop will be broken by the completed `postDelayed()` as `proceed` will be set to true in it, then the code can continues the `for` loop.

But I not sure why it simply doesn't work. When I run the code, it just displayed a blank screen. It seemed like the problem resides within the infitine `while` loop and `postDelayed()` can't update the `proceed` variable.

I tried using `Thread.sleep(1000)` as a replacement of `postDelayed`, but during startup, the program simply shows a white background for however long the parameter is passed to `Thread.sleep()`

I have exhausted my option and I hope someone has a better idea.
Thank you.

Comment: " The for loop doesn't wait for the postDelayed to finish whatever it is suppose to do" - no, `for` loop shouldn't wait for `postDelayed`. and with `while(!proceed) {}` line you are hanging UI thread probably...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop does not wait for the postDelayed because what's inside the postDelayed happens async. This means that it works independently from the UI thread, on a second thread. What you want to accomplish is to make the UIthread wait for a period of time, and not start another thread after a specific period.
You could try to use the handler in this way:

```
Handler handler=new Handler()
{

public void handleMessage(Message msg)
{
   if(msg.what==0)
{
 viewCard11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_view_circle3);
      proceed = true;
}

}
};
```

and then you may use the handler like this:

```
handler.postDelayed(() -> 
{            
 //does nothing just waits 1 second and then send empty message
 handler.sendEmptyMessage(0)
}, 1000);
```